# Loop through XML with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to using `Linq` and `XMLDocument`.

I have a simple XML file and I want to loop through all of the elements and print the tag and value. I don't want to use the XML Tags when looping through. this is what I have so far.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Step1>One
<Step2>Two
    <Step3>Three
        <Step4>Four
        </Step4>
    </Step3>
</Step2>
</Step1>
```

C# Code

```
  private void StartIt()
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xd = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xd.Load(@"C:\Projects\GetXML\testLayers.xml");

        XmlNodeList nl = xd.SelectNodes("Layer1");

        foreach (XmlNode xnode in nl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xnode.Name + " = " + xnode.InnerText); // + " " +   xnode.InnerXml);
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
 Step1 = One
Two
    Three
        Four
```

What I want:

```
Step1 = One
Step2 = Two
Step3 = Three
Step4 = Four
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you want to use XMLDocument rather than LINQ to XML? The latter is much simpler to use, IMO.

Comment: No not really from what I was reading it seemed to be the most used method.

Answer (score 2):

With a little help of Linq,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fname);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*[text()]")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(n => new { 
                    Name= n.Name, 
                    Value = n.SelectSingleNode("text()").Value
                })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// System.Xml.XmlDocument version
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(@"C:\Projects\GetXML\testLayers.xml");
foreach (XmlElement step in xd.SelectNodes("//*"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", step.Name,
       step.SelectSingleNode("text()").Value);
}

// System.Xml.Linq.XDocument version
XDocument xdLinq = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Projects\GetXML\testLayers.xml");
foreach (XElement step in xdLinq.XPathSelectElements("//*"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", step.Name, 
       step.Nodes().Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using **LINQ to XML** and `XDocument` class:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

foreach (var e in xDoc.Descendants())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", e.Name, e.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value.Trim());
}
```